# I am facing this problem while uploading the flutter app on the App Store

Tags: ios, flutter

App Store Connect

Dear Developer,
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "App Name" 1.0.4 (4). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

**ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.** Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).
Best regards,
The App Store Team

**pubspec.yaml**

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  simple_animations: ^1.3.3
  flutter_screenutil: ^0.4.2
  carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.4
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.6.7
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+12
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.3
  google_sign_in: ^4.4.4
  flutter_map: ^0.8.2
  intl_phone_field: ^1.4.2
  flare_flutter: ^2.0.1
  giffy_dialog: ^1.8.0
  http: ^0.12.2
  intl: ^0.16.1
  flutter_dialogs: ^1.1.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.8.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6
  url_launcher: ^5.7.10
  contactus: ^1.1.7
  contact_picker: ^0.0.2
  nice_button: ^0.1.7
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.3
  date_format: ^1.0.9
  flip_card: ^0.4.4
  expansion_card: ^0.1.0
  lamp: ^0.0.6
  pinput: ^0.2.6
  share: ^0.6.5+4
  country_list_pick: ^1.0.1+3
  permission_handler: ^5.0.0
  contacts_service: ^0.3.10
  wc_flutter_share: ^0.2.2
  connectivity: ^2.0.2
  popup_menu: ^1.0.5
  quick_actions: 0.5.0+1
  rxdart: ^0.26.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1+1
  badges: ^1.1.6
  provider: ^4.3.3
  flutter_ringtone_player: ^2.0.0
  introduction_screen: ^1.0.9
  sms_autofill: ^1.2.7
  r_scan:
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0
  flutter_switch: ^0.2.2
  lottie: any
```

Comment: do a full text search in your .pub cache folder for "UIWebView". It will list all your dependencies that might use it. Then consider replacing, removing, rewriting, upgrading those plugins. It really comes to that, from here 'https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60687#issuecomment-671186726'

Answer (score 1):

[Please read this article, it helps you to solve your issue.](https://ionicframework.com/blog/understanding-itms-90809-uiwebview-api-deprecation/)

The App Store will no longer accept new apps using UIWebView. Please check in application where you used UIWebView or any dependency is using internally UIWebView. if you found any dependencies then replace that with another which use Webkit instead of UIWebView. And then submit application to app store.